# cloning from repository to desktop github is not possible

Tags: git

1. I have cloned my repository but it always shows like this.

   fatal: bad config line 1 in file C:/Users/Win10/.gitconfig. Would you like to retry cloning?
2. i have opened with `ssh` because i am using `http`but always can't clone to github desktop.

Comment: make sure to use the appropriate tags for your question

Comment: Well, have you checked what the first line of the `.gitconfig` file is?

Comment: the first line is like this
<?xml version="1.0"?>

Answer (score 0):

Your git configurations (Local, Global, System) are only allowed to contain key/value pairs in sections defined by brackets, e.g. `[user]` or `[alias]`. You're allowed to have comments, e.g. `#This is a comment`.

The following is not a valid start to a `.gitconfig` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

The following is a valid start to a `.gitconfig` file:

```
# This is Git's per-user configuration file.                                                                                                                                                                      
[user]                                                                                                                                                                                                            
name = Martin Kjeldsen                                                                                                                                                                                            
email = martin.kjeldsen@mail.dk
```